# json with autocomplete not filter data

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I have this simple autocomplete with json results but it  keep getting me all the data from my database table instead of data according to  search terms entered to search box

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#searchTerm").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("FindSubjectsName", "Profile")',
                //data: "{'searchTerm': '" + request.searchTerm + "' }",
                data: { searchTerm: request.searchTerm },
                dataType: 'json',
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.value,
                            value: item.value,
                            id: item.id,
                        }
                    }))
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
    });
});
```

**C#**

```
public JsonResult FindSubjectsName(string searchTerm)
{
    var results = db.subjects.Where(s => searchTerm == null ||
        s.SubjectName.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower())).Select(x => new
        { id = x.SubjectId, value = x.SubjectName }).Distinct().ToList();
    return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: How is the request.searchTerm being populated? Is the value being passed model binded in the controller?

Comment: Bon Macalindong >>public ActionResult UsersReview(string searchTerm)
        {
            IEnumerable<PostViewModel> viewModel = from review in db.reviews.OrderBy(d => d.Created)
                                                        .Include(s => s.subject)
                                                         .Where(r => r.subject.SubjectName.Contains(searchTerm)).Distinct() And so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public JsonResult FindSubjectsName(string searchTerm)
        {
            var results = db.subjects.Where(s => s.SubjectName.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower())).
                Select(x => new { id = x.SubjectId, value = x.SubjectName }).Distinct().ToList();
            return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: unfortunately .. the same all data from db is populated

Comment: does the searchTerm parameter has a value? I don't see anything wrong in amrit sandhu's code

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a stored proc. This way the application's performance is faster and if you need to change the filtering logic, you can easily do it rather than changing the code and re-building the application.

1 Create the Stored Proc

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetSubjects
@SearchText VARCHAR
AS
BEGIN
    Select * from Subjects Where SubjectName LIKE '%' + @SearchText + '%'
END
GO
```

2 Update your Entity Data Model. Right click and select Update Model from Database. This will automatically add the stored proc you just created to the DataContext.

```
public JsonResult FindSubjectsName(string searchTerm)
{
   <YOURDATACONTEXT> db = new <YOURDATACONTEXT>();
   var result = db.GetSubjects(searchTerm);
   return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

3. Jquery and Front End Code remains unchanged.